# aws ec2 comand works, aws iam command fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

This is an odd one for sure. I have an aws command line user that I've setup with admin privileges in the AWS account. The credentials I generated for the user work when I issue an aws ec2 command. But not when I run an aws iam command.

When I run the aws iam command, this is what I get:

```
[user@web1:~] #aws iam create-account-alias --account-alias=mcollective

An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the CreateAccountAlias operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

However when I run an aws ec2 subcommand using the same credentials, I get a success:

```
[root@web1:~] #aws ec2 describe-instances --profile=mcollective
RESERVATIONS    281933881942    r-0080cb499a0299557
INSTANCES       0       x86_64  146923690580740912      False   xen     ami-6d1c2007    i-00dcdb6cbff0d7980     t2.micro        mcollective  2016-07-27T23:56:50.000Z        ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal       xx.xx.xx.xx   ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com        xx.xxx.xx.xx    /dev/sda1       ebs     True            subnet-0e734056 hvm     vpc-909103f7
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPINGS     /dev/sda1
EBS     2016-07-23T01:26:42.000Z        False   attached        vol-0eb52f6a94c5833aa
MONITORING      disabled
NETWORKINTERFACES               0e:68:20:c5:fa:23       eni-f78223ec    281933881942    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal   xxx.xx.xx.xx   True    in-use  subnet-0e734056 vpc-909103f7
ASSOCIATION     281933881942    ec2-xxx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com        xx.xx.xx.xx
ATTACHMENT      2016-07-23T01:26:41.000Z        eni-attach-cbf11a1f     True    0       attached
GROUPS  sg-b1b3bdca     CentOS 7 -x86_64- - with Updates HVM-1602-AutogenByAWSMP-
PRIVATEIPADDRESSES      True    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal   xxx.xx.xx.xx
ASSOCIATION     281933881942    ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com        xx.xx.xx.xx
PLACEMENT       us-east-1a              default
PRODUCTCODES    aw0evgkw8e5c1q413zgy5pjce       marketplace
SECURITYGROUPS  sg-b1b3bdca     CentOS 7 -x86_64- - with Updates HVM-1602-AutogenByAWSMP-
STATE   16      running
TAGS    Name     mcollective
You have mail in /var/spool/mail/root
[root@web1:~] #
```

So why the heck are the same credentials working for one set of aws subcommands, but not another? I'm really curious about this one!

Comment: Change your user to root and then run this command aws iam create-account-alias --account-alias=mcollective and see if it works?

Comment: Are you sure you have the same credentials configured for both the `user` and the `root` accounts?

Comment: You are passing a ``--profile`` option on the EC2 command but you aren't on the IAM command.

Comment: yup! that was it. Sorry, that was a long day.. sigh! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered by @garnaat, but the answer was buried in the comments of the question, so quoting the answer here for those who glaze over it:

Different profiles are being used in each command through use of `--profile` flag

Explanation:

In the first command

`[user@web1:~] #aws iam create-account-alias --account-alias=mcollective`

`--profile` is not specified, so the default aws profile credentials are automatically used

In the second command

`aws ec2 describe-instances --profile=mcollective`

`--profile` is specified, which overrides the default profile